# VS2017: Where can I find the command-line for the Driver-Signing properties?

Tags: visual-studio

I seldom use the latest version of Visual Studio, however now that the DDK started getting integrated as of VS2015, I wanted to play around with the driver integration for VS2017.  Problem is, I've noticed its hard to see where some variables are coming from such as the %(PreprocessorDefinitions) DEFINES, which I did eventually find.

Along a similar vein, I've got a "legacy" WDM driver project in VS2017.  When I build the project, the resulting .SYS file gets signed.  So far so good.

```
Successfully signed: c:\some_path\xyz.sys
```

In project properties I can change some variables within the "Driver Signing" property sheet, however its embedded command line property sheet is empty. I do however see a check mark in 'Inherit from parent of project defaults" but I don't see where I can find code-signing "project defaults".  I'd like to see the command-line being used to sign my .SYS files (for modification or not).  Doing a last-ditch search of the filesystem in paths for Visual Studio, the DDK being used, and user config area aren't finding much (searching for signtool.exe, "Successfully signed", etc.).

Can anyone point me to the batch file/script/command-line definition for the signing of drivers?  I'm not finding much on MSDN as help for this particular property sheet seems to be absent.  Am I missing something obvious?  I'm finding it difficult that project settings are strewn across different files and not displayable in some central location from the VS GUI.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the command line is hard-coded in the following DLLs:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll
```

I was expecting these commands to be in a text-file (XML or otherwise), so it looks like the command line can't be altered directly without disabling signing and adding a custom post-build step if the signing features within the projects dialog don't meet your needs.

NOTE: I didn't originally find these DLLs because they are present as WIDE strings;  the findstr tool which I was using for the search doesn't support WIDE strings, at least without manually inserting wildcard (dot) characters for the NULLs.  The signtool command line does however get written to intermediate .tlog files during the build process, just without the path to signtool.exe.